# Random variable $X$ has Poisson's distribution. If $P(X = 1) = P(X = 2)$ calculate expectation, dispersion and probability of $Y = \{5 \leq X\}$.

Tags: probability

Random variable $X$ has Poisson's distribution. If $P(X =
1) = P(X = 2)$ calculate expectation, dispersion and probability of $Y = \{5 \leq X\}$.

From $P(X =1) = P(X = 2)$ I easily got $\lambda = 2$, but now I am stuck at expextation (which I tried to calculate by definition).

Comment: Well, $\lambda$ *is* the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is defined as having a Poisson distribution and you have found its only parameter $\lambda$ then you know its mean and variance, each of which is exactly $\lambda$.

Comment: What about its dispersion? Can you give me a hint about that too? And thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Dispersion i another name for variance equal also to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ ~ $Poisson(\lambda) \Rightarrow E(X) = Var(X) = \lambda ~\forall~ \lambda$. To calculate $P(X \geq 5)$ just use the Poisson $cdf$. In particular,

$$P(X \geq 5) = 1 - F_X(5) $$

I have never seen the notation "dispersion" to mean Variance, but I imagine $Var(X) = Dispersion(X)$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, in my language it is called both variance and dispersion so I figured it is common in english too.